# Unable to check the checkbox using angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Here is my issue. I am unable to trigger the checkbox select on firing an event/Function when ever the function is called. The input has to be selected like below

TS code:

```
check(){
   this.selectAll = true;
   let elements = this.hostElement.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('deltha');
   for(var i=0;i<elements.length;i++){
       elements[i].selected= this.selectAll;
   }
}
```

HTML code:

```
 <input type="checkbox" id="selectAll" [(ngModel)]="selectAll" (change)="selectAllFiles($event)" class="form-check-input deltha">
```

Whenever the function is called, it has to trigger and this check box has to be checked here. I am not using and reactive/template form approach as this has to be a unique one. When I am trying the above function code, it's not working and it is not giving any error as well...

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue. Could you provide a representation in stackblitz ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what's the issue here. You'll need to provide more code so we could try to reproduce your problem.

From what i see here when you change this.selectAll to true then the checkbox is selected (you don't need to do this by applying anything to the element) - you can see this in the stackbliz demo - https://stackblitz.com/edit/checkbox-selection-1?file=src/app/app.component.ts

please add more information to your question.